# How to replace a name in the datatable using sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want to replace the repeated customer name in the list of record in sql server

below is how the query result is...

```
CustomerName      ||      Product

CustomerA         ||      Product    X
CustomerA         ||      Product    y
CustomerA         ||      Product    z
CustomerB         ||      Product    i  
CustomerB         ||      Product    j
```

I want to get result like below...

```
CustomerName      ||      Product

CustomerA         ||      Product    X
"No Name"         ||      Product    y
"No Name"         ||      Product    z
CustomerB         ||      Product    i  
"No Name"         ||      Product    j
```

please suggest, what will be the best to achieve the above result...

Thanks
Aman

Comment: you should replace in your application view layer, not the database!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want or need to do this as a query, you can use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to determine which is and isn't the "first" product per customer. Here I've defined "first" to mean having the lexically smallest Product name ([fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/356e1/2)):

```
;WITH CustomerProducts AS
(
    SELECT CustomerName, Product, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerName ORDER BY Product) rn
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN CustomerName ELSE '"Same Customer"' END CustomerName,
    Product
FROM CustomerProducts
ORDER BY CustomerProducts.CustomerName, Product
```